# How to procedurally generate terrain to make an infinite terrain?

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain, procedural-generation

I have been researching this subject just about everywhere I can find it, but all everyone talks about is the mathematical side to things, not about *how* to make an infinite randomly generated terrain. I am pretty new to Unity, so when say things like "just tile it," I have no idea *how* to tile. I've heard about the diamond-square algorithm, but I don't know how to apply an algorithm to the terrain. Perlin noise I only know how to apply as far as the terrain toolkit to one terrain tile. Any help would be really, really appreciated!

Comment: This site helped me soooo much... I'm sure it will do the same for you http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/tutorial-procedural-meshes-and-voxel-terrain-c.198651/

Comment: http://code-phi.com/infinite-terrain-generation-in-unity-3d/